# NUXT JS multiple dynamic parameters

Tags: routes, vue-router, nuxt.js

I have a folder structure like bellow,

```
---|company
-----|_id
-------|branch
---------|_id
-----------|user
-----------|create.vue
```

Now, the path belongs to creating an user, which is create by nuxt itself, is '**client-company-id-branch-id-user**'
I have used router push inside the method to go to that route

```
this.$router.push({
      params: {
          id: this.$route.params.id
          id: branch_id
       },
        name: 'client-company-id-branch-id-user',
  })
```

Here, I need to pass two dynamic id, one is company id, and the other is branch id. Now the problem is, on the route name both parameters have the same name.

Now changing the folder(_id) name could be one solution. 
Are there any alternative solution????